# Group and sort the rows of a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

I have a table where column `A` contains a unique value in every cell. Column `B` is either empty or contains a number.

```
   |    A    | B 
---+---------+---
 1 | Gamma   | 1 
 2 | Echo    | 5 
 3 | Alpha   |   
 4 | Foxtrot | 3 
 5 | Bravo   |   
 6 | Charlie | 1 
 7 | Delta   |
```

I would like to sort the table such that the rows with a non-blank value in the `B` column appear before those with a blank in that column. The rows with non-blank values in `B` also need to be sorted alphabetically by column `A`. The sort order of the other rows is irrelevant.

The result should look something like this:

```
   |    A    | B 
---+---------+---
 1 | Charlie | 1 
 2 | Echo    | 5 
 3 | Foxtrot | 3 
 4 | Gamma   | 1 
 5 | Alpha   |   
 6 | Bravo   |   
 7 | Delta   |
```

As of right now, the blank cells in column `B` are completely empty, not even containing a formula that evaluates to a null string. In the future, that will probably change. I don't know if this will affect any answers.

Comment: So far, the best that I've been able to come up with is to sort by the column with numbers (column B), Hide all of the empty rows, and then alphabetically sort column A. It seems as thought this is the only option, unless someone has something that works for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* actually a no-hiding-of-rows, no-filtering, **single**-sort solution. It just requires a simple conditional formatting formula to be added to column `B`:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing Conditional Formatting Rules]

Select `B2:B8`, making sure that `B2` is the active cell, and add a new formula conditional formatting rule. Change the rule's font colour to anything other than `Automatic` and enter the following as the formula:

```dart
=B2=""
```

Note that while a header row is shown, it is not required. (See the notes at the bottom of [my other answer](//superuser.com/a/1342366) for further details.)

Now, all you need to do to get the desired result is this two-level sort:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing Sort Order]

1. Sort by column `B` on `Font Color` ordered by `Automatic` `On Top`
2. Sort by column `A` on `Values` ordered by `A to Z`

The same effect can be achieved by using a fill colour instead of a font colour for the conditional formatting rule and sorting on `Cell Color`. (By using the font colour, it is simpler to make no visible change appear for the data. I used red so it would be obvious in the screenshot, but the best colour to use for the general case would be black.)

---

Note that sorting can be accessed either via the `Data`→`Sort & Filter`→`Sort` menu, the shortcut equivalent <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or from **any** of the in-cell dropdowns when Filter Mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) is turned on (provided, of course, there is a header row, empty or  not, as otherwise the sort cannot be guaranteed to work correctly):

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing how to access Custom Sort from In-cell Dropdown]

---

In essence, sorting by colour adds a "grouping" feature when sorting, similar to what's available in SQL.

This grouping can be quite complex, including using multiple columns for the criteria, whilst still only requiring a two-level sort. Even "nested" groupings can be performed - they just require extra sort levels.

Comment: This is great!   I didn’t know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the no-hiding-of-rows, no-filtering, no-helper-column, no-conditional-formatting, **two**-sort, three-step solution I mentioned in a comment on the OP's self-answer. It has been confirmed as working in Excel 2007.

**Step 1**

Sort by column `B` on `Values` ordered by `Smallest to Largest`:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing First Sort]

Note that while a header row is shown, it is not required. (See the notes for further details.)

**Step 2**

Select the top part of the table down as far as the last row with a non-blank value in column `B`. For the example table this would be `A1:C5`.

The best way to do this for a large number of rows and/or columns (but applies equally well for smaller tables and avoids scrolling manually or using the mouse) is the following keyboard shortcut sequence, starting from any non-blank cell in the `B` column:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> as many times as required to get to the rightmost column of the table (or just hold it down to get to the right edge of the sheet);
- (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> if you overshoot and end up at the start of the next table or the rightmost column of the sheet);
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>;

If there is no other data to the right of the table, this alternate sequence can by used instead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>;
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

**Step 3**

Sort by column `A` on `Values` ordered by `A to Z`:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing Second Sort]

---

**Notes:**

- The sort in step 1 can be performed either via the `Data`→`Sort & Filter`→`Sort` menu item (or its shortcut equivalent <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
  ) or from the in-cell dropdown when Filter Mode is turned on (provided there is a header row, of course).
- The sort is step 3 can *only* be performed via the menu item.
- This method is guaranteed to work even if the table data starts in row `1` and has no header row. *Only* my two solutions (plus the OP's, of course) will work for this case. In fact those solutions are the only ones that will work, or can even be made to work, for a header-less, row `1` table if the first cell of column `B` is a blank.
- It will also work irrespective of the Filter Mode state. (Unless, of course, the table is headerless, starts in row one, and for some reason Filter Mode is turned on. In which case turn it off and leave it off already!)

Comment: :D I feel addressed by the introduction: But you still need to manually select only part of the table. This will by scrolling if it's a big table and the cells aren't empty. But now I can explain why I "choose" to described my alternative instead of the other ones: My solution won't change or need more time to execute when the data sets get bigger. And it does not need to use auxiliary columns. To give you some credit: I like the diversity of you're ideas! :) So, let's close our debate now, ok?!

Comment: Scrolling is *not* ¹ required in large tables for this solution (unlike for other ones). It requires just three keyboard shortcuts.² Nor will it *"change"* (???) or *"need more time to execute"* (???) when the data set gets bigger. Nor does it use *"auxiliary"* (helper?) columns. … ¹ Even if column `B` is instead another column further to the right, for example `ZZ:ZZ`. In which case the sequence `Ctrl`+`G`; `ZZ:ZZ`; `Enter` will get you there. (Note that this case would impact this solution *less* than some other solutions.) … ² Slightly more than three under ***very*** unusual circumstances.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want to end the debate. So first I would like to check, what is you're goal here? Do you just want to hear that you are right, or are you are really interested in this matter thus willing *and motivated* to discuss it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there isn't a way to do what I want *strictly* through sorting, but here's what works for me:

1. Sort rows by Column B from small to large
2. Hide all the rows that do
   not have a value in Column B
3. Sort rows by Column A alphabetically

Comment: As an alternative to hiding the rows in step (2), you could simply select the part of the table which *does* have values in column `B`. The sort  in step (3) will then occur on the selected sub-table only (provided you sort via `Data`→`Sort & Filter`→`Sort` and not from the in-cell Filter Mode dropdown). The advantage of this method is that you don't end up with hidden rows. (This may or  may not be an issue in your particular case.)

Comment: I thought I tried I already and it still sorted the entire table, even the non highlighted area.

Comment: I only tried in Excel 2007, but I expect it should still work for more recent versions. Can you confirm whether it does/does not work with your version of Excel?

Comment: is there a reason that you don't "unhide" the hidden rows?

Comment: I'm not unhiding the rows at this moment because I'm using this file to manage a collection; I'm making edits to the file, and I'm only interested in the rows where I'm using the items in the collection.

Answer (score -2):

One solution would be to to combine sorting and filtering. It works best if you have column headers in the first row, but it does not need them necessarily.

It's not "just sorting", as you requested, it uses the filter. But you can just "select" the whole table (actually turning on the filter mode will do that for you), follow the steps and voilà. Also it's fairly easy to "convert" it into a macro. In regards to the other solutions this solution doesn't require you to hide (or "unselect") the undesired rows manually. Nor do you have to introduce a additional formula (through conditional formatting of column A or B, or by adding another column).

Anyway here it goes:

**Turn on the filter:**

- select any cell in your list and turn on the filter mode (in the ribbon you'll find it under the tab "Data", it should be called "Filter"). You'll see little triangle appear in the first row of each column you use

  (note: if you don't have column headers just add an empty row in the very beginning and select all used columns manually, in this case A and B, instead of "just" selecting a cell in the list)

**Move the rows without B-Value to the end of the list:**

- sort column B in ascending order (by clicking the small triangle-button in the first row of column B and selecting sort by value ascending)

**Sort the A-column and turn off/remove filter**

- filter the rows that have empty cells in column B (again by clicking the triangle-button and by unchecking the value "empty" at the bottom of the list)
- sort column A in ascending order (same way you sorted column B)
- turn off advanced filtering (same way you turned it on), this will automatically remove the filter for empty cells in column B

That should give you the right result as far as I understood you. You also won't have to hid any rows manually, excel will hide all the rows for you.

(please note, hiding rows manually is different from using the filter to "hide" them)

Comment: anything I might improve, so I get rid of the down-votes? suggestions are appreciated!